# Getting original width and height of a image

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have an image, lets say it is referred by a variable `var IMG = $("img")` I want to capture its original height and width. I am using below code. It works well but it is not working in Win XP IE8. Can anyone please tell me what the issue is?

```
$("<img/>")
    .attr("src", IMG.attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        //Execution is not coming in this block
        alert(this.width);

    });
```

Comment: I vaguely recall something about the load event not firing if the image file is cached. Could that be it?

Comment: Bind the `load` handler and *then* set the `src` attribute.

Comment: @techfoobar - did not understood what u r saying

Comment: @MotaBOS - Check A. Wolff's answer.

Comment: If you set the src before setting the load handler, loading might be over (especially for cached images) before the load handler is bound and it won't be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should in all case set `src` after `onload` handler, especially for cached image, try and see if that's make a difference:

```
$("<img/>")    
    .load(function() {
        //Execution is not coming in this block
        alert(this.width);

    })
    .attr("src", IMG.attr("src"));
```